# Adding Events to user control in Windows forms

Tags: c#

I am using a windows form in which i have a build a usercontrol with one textbox and one CheckedList control. What i wanted to do is i want to capture the ListIndexChanged event of CheckListbox control in my form where i use this usercontrol.

Please help me how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this

```
public event EventHandler SelectedIndexChanged
{
    add { checkListBox.SelectedIndexChanged += value; }
    remove { checkListBox.SelectedIndexChanged -= value; }
}
```

to your control and subscribe to this event from the form

take a look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/fd45e5c9-b28a-4883-bf3b-5ce680f2d775/)